# Update UI UWP Page Application

Tags: c#, user-interface, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make a Wumpus World in C#.
These are some classes:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="MundoWumpus.SecondPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MundoWumpus"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Padding="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Mundo de Wumpus" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,10" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="myContent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

SecondPage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// O modelo do item de página em branco está documentado em http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace MundoWumpus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Uma página vazia que pode ser usada isoladamente ou navegada dentro de um Quadro.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class SecondPage : Page
    {
        public SecondPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            int size = (int)e.Parameter();

            World world = new World(size);
            WorldCanvas wrldCanvas = new WorldCanvas(size);
            myContent.Content = WrldCanvas;
        }
    }
}
```

CanvasWorld is a class that derives from Canvas. I have to initialize it after in the SecondPage because it needs a parameter (size) that is received from the MainPage. The CanvasWorld(size) is a method constructor that makes a grade of squares. I want to know how to update the SecondPage, because the wrldCanvas is initialized after and it appears on the page, but not aligned.

[SecondPage Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOWlh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are right about overriding the [OnNavigatedTo method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto.aspx), but your `OnNavigatedTo` method will not be triggered when navigated to the `SecondPage`.

This method should be like this:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
     //your code here
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for observation. But it´s protected. I just wrote wrong!

Comment: @SérgioDamasceno， please notice that the parameter of this method should be `NavigationEventArgs e`, not `EventArgs e`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to put your new `CanvasWorld` object where you already have a `Canvas` named `wrldCanvas`: There are several approaches, the easiest probably involving replacing your placeholder Canvas with something more practical, like a `ContentControl`, then setting its `Content` property to your new `CanvasWorld`.

The XAML line with the `Canvas`should change to something like this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="myContent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

...and the code-behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    int size = (int)e.Parameter; // Property, not method

    World world = new World(size); // Not clear to me what this is or does?
    myContent.Content = new CanvasWorld(size);
}
```

(Side issue: In your code you used the name `wrldCanvas` for one of the local variable in `OnNavigatedTo`, the same as the field name you gave to the `Canvas` declared in the XAML. While this is neither illegal nor stops you from referencing both (by referencing the field as `this.wrldCanvas`), it's a recipe for confusion, in my mind. Better if local variables don't mask fields...)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I used them to improve my code.